# Angular2 frequency of @Input() values

Tags: angular

I have a child component, which receives some values through `@Input()`:

```
<my-component
    [model]="node"
    [required]="isRequired()"
>
</my-component>
```

`[required]` passes the return value of the `isRequired()` method, as you can see. 
But it could become quite perfomance hungry, so i would like to limit how often it is queried.

Is there some way to configure how often angular calls `isRequired()`?

Comment: are you ok with using `Observable` or you need to migrate some legacy code (Angular 1) to Angular 4 and not being able to use `Observable` too early in the process?

Comment: Some info here may help: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: @andreim I don't migrate. `Observable` would be okay, I guess. But I don't know where this is leading.

Comment: @DeborahK I read about change detection. But as I understood it, it is about how the child component handles changes in the return values of `isRequired()`. I think `isRequired()` is called and the result is handled by the change detection. But then it's too late. `isRequired()` was already executed. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Reynicke you have several data architectures that you can use with Angular: 1) passing inputs and outputs; 2) passing observables; 3) Redux. Note that 3) Redux can be used with Observables for side effects, thus having [Redux-Observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/). Depending on your use case (how complex is your app...) you can opt between these architectures.

Comment: @Reynicke you have `isRequired()`  function, but instead of passing the function as an input, you can just set a `isRequired` field to a value computed when its body variables change. For example `function isRequired() { return a === 123 ? true : false; }`. You might as well write it as, when the variable `a` changes then just set a field `this.aInput.valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.someIsRequiredField = this.isRequired())` then pass `someIsRequiredField` as an input to `<my-component>`. In this example I considered that you are using `ReactiveFormsModule` and thus `FormControl#valueChanges`

Comment: @Reynicke you should pass only values and references to inputs, not functions or expressions. This will make it easier to understand the code and make performance improvements. The semantics can be: if the inputs do change then the change detector of the `<my-component>` component should start evaluating, else nothing should happen. You can enable this behavior using `@Component({ changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush })`. Therefore in this case you will not have all child change detectors be triggered because the parent change detector was triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that. Angular creates a factory for the parent component that houses `MyComponent` with the `updateDirectives` function that is called on each change detection cycle when the parent component is being checked. For details read [The mechanics of property bindings update in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/the-mechanics-of-property-bindings-update-in-angular-39c0812bc4ce). You can not disable a change detection specifically for bindings. If you detach a change detector, no [operations from change detection](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f) will be performed.

What you probably could do is to create a provider service on the parent component and have your child `MyComponent` component inject it and query for the `isRequired` whenever it wants. Something along these lines:

```
@Component({template: `<my-component...>`, provider: [SomeService]})
export class ParentComponent {}

@Component({})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(service: SomeService) {
    service.isRequired();
  }
}
```